# Set mat expansion panel to page top when clicked from one of many panel list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a scenario, dynamically I render panel through ngFor loop with dynamic mat content upon mat panel expansion and mat content is mapped via an API response asynchronously and I can only show one-panel expansion at a time, attached is my issue video and StackBlitz code. I'm sorry I don't know how to explain my problem so I'm posting a video of my issue. attaching the code snippet below

https://www.screencast.com/t/G9IHGF9R - As you can see when I'm trying to open any panel when another panel is already open my panel content is getting hidden along with the panel header.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyvcxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-expand-collapse-all-example.ts

Actually the mat content of all panels is driven with only one variable the value

What I want to achieve is when I expand my panel it should not get hidden rather clicked panel should open at the same place or get it at the top of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to open multiple panels.

Try this <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align" **[multi]="true"**>

Comment: No, I want to open only one panel at a time, Let me rewrite my question again.

Comment: I have updated the StackBlitz, Actually, Mat-content is driven from a same variable to all panels from an API response. And when I'm expanding the next panel my currently clicked panel header is getting hidden.

Comment: It seems to behave the way it should.On expanding the next panel, currently clicked panel header stays and is visible( not hidden).Can't understand what you are trying to point here.